# Android - Draw smooth animation of path in google maps

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm trying to develop an animation which draws on the map a path taken from kml file.

You can see what I'm trying to achieve [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/?hl=es) (select 'flat markers' and play video).

I know how read a kml file so this is what I have:

```
<when xmlns="">2016-02-06T10:35:45</when>
<gx:coord xmlns="">-3.712957966518081 40.1 751.9160934840661</gx:coord>
<gx:angles xmlns="">236.0 -26.0 0</gx:angles>

<when xmlns="">2016-02-06T10:35:50</when>
<gx:coord xmlns="">-3.712996048182038 40.43415773827724 743.6413204016039</gx:coord>
<gx:angles xmlns="">222.0 -12.0 -3</gx:angles>

<when xmlns="">2016-02-06T10:35:51</when>
<gx:coord xmlns="">-3.713017934633122 40.43416573356486 743.6247498523435</gx:coord>
<gx:angles xmlns="">240.0 -24.0 -7</gx:angles>

<when xmlns="">2016-02-06T10:35:52</when>
<gx:coord xmlns="">-3.7127268 40.4342039 0.0</gx:coord>
<gx:angles xmlns="">244.0 -12.0 -6</gx:angles>

<when xmlns="">2016-02-06T10:35:53</when>
<gx:coord xmlns="">-3.71306454726805 40.434187799343604 743.5952983506019</gx:coord>
<gx:angles xmlns="">224.0 -13.0 -9</gx:angles>
```

As you can see I have a list of locations with its respective times.

How can I make an animation of the list locations like this?

Comment: You need to convert the lat/lng to screen coordinates (x,y) and then you can simply use translate animation to animate marker + the location's bearing will help you determine the true heading and you can rotate the map accordingly!

Comment: So there is not way to do it on google_map by default?